# How to get report_name in Qweb header in Odoo 10?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I need to show a string in the header of several reports which must change depending on the report which is being printed.

By now, I had done this:

```
<template id="external_layout_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
    ...
    <t t-if="o._table=='sale_order'">
        ... Print here what I need to show in sale order reports ...
    </t>
    ...
</template>
```

It worked well for me, but now, the string does not depend on the model/table, but on the printed report.

I have a model which has two different reports to print. If one is printed, I have to show 'X' in the header, if the other one is printed, I have to show 'Y' in the header. There is no difference between them, I mean, there is no attribute in the model which allows me identify them.

For example, in a previous case, despite having the same model, I was able to show the correct string due to the `state` field value:

```
<template id="external_layout_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
    ...
    <t t-if="o._table=='sale_order'">
        <t t-if="o.state=='draft'">
            ... Print Sale Quotation ...
        </t>
        <t t-if="o.state!='draft'">
            ... Print Sale Order ...
        </t>
    </t>
    ...
</template>
```

But in this case there is no field which helps me. Only the report name, so I need to get it from the header.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try the report parser, from there you can easily distinguish reports by theire names.

Comment: Yes, look into `render_html()` you probably need to override it, to update `docargs` with your report as an object.

Comment: Thank you both, I guess @EasyOdoo solution is easier than inheriting from those methods, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this and it worked hope you get the idea. First there is some
fact that I know (but not for sure) that made me came with this logic.

1. There is no direct way to set a attribute on `docs` or `o`(RecordSet passed to report) on Qweb.
2. We have access to context `o.env.context`.
3. when you call a template inside another the last one have access to the the scope of the first template.

Instead of adding attribute why we don't just add a key to the magic attribute context using `o.with_context`
using the power of `t-set` we can add an extra `key` but we need to make sure we do this before
we call `<t t-call="report.external_layout">` in the report template so the `external_layout` can find 
that extra `key` on the context ^^

```xml
 <!-- add extra key to context -->
 <!-- you can set it one time on docs it's better -->
 <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(report_name='hello_report')"/> 
 <t t-call="report.external_layout">
```

Now because context is frozendict instance or something like it (I'm not sure), we can use `get` with default
value to check if that special key is passed on the context.

```xml
<template id="external_layout_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
        ...
        <t t-if="o.env.context.get('report_name', False) == 'hello_report'">
                   <!-- show what you want to show  for this report -->
```

Or you can make it even better by making this behavior generale by just passing the value itself in the context
this will minimize number of `if statements` on you external_layout .

```xml
<template id="external_layout_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
        ...
        <t t-if="o.env.context.get('extra_value', False)">
              <p t-esc="o.env.context.get('extra_value')"></p>
```

So for any report that you need it to have this behavior.
if it's existing one inherit the template and make sure that you add the key before calling `external_layout` using `x-path`.

**Edits:**

an example of the result this is in odoo `8.0` I didn't use inherit I directly updated the remplates.

sale.order template

```xml
<template id="report_saleorder_document">
    <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(extra_info='show this on header')"/>
    <t t-call="report.external_layout">
```

external layout on report

```xml
 <template id="external_layout_header">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <t t-if=" 'extra_info' in o.env.context" >
                    <p t-esc="o.env.context.get('extra_info')"></p>
                </t>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
            </div>
            ....
            .....
            ...
```

result is this

[image: final result]

Comment: Brilliant answer, again! Thank you very much Cherif.

Comment: Thanks you another hard question too, i'm wrong in one thing you can ckeck if an object has attribute `'some_attribute' in o`  forget about it LOL.